# Proof-verification: Bolzano Weierstrass theorem (modified)

Tags: proof-verification

I want to show that every bounded sequence has a subsequence that converge. Do you agree with my proof and if not, what's wrong ?

**Proof**

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$ a bounded sequence. Since $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$ is bounded, $\limsup_{n\to\infty }(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$ exist. Indeed, if we set for all $n$, $$y_n:=\sup_{k\geq n}x_k,$$ the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$ is decreasing and bounded end thus convergente. Let $$\ell:=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\sup_{k\geq n}x_k=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N} y_n.$$

Let $k\in\mathbb N^*$. By definition of $\ell$,
$$\exists n_k\in\mathbb N: |y_{n_k}-\ell|<\frac{1}{2k}.$$

We can suppose with out loss of generality that $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N^*}$ is strictly increasing. Indeed, by convergence of $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N^*}$,
$$\exists n_{k+1}>n_k:\forall n\in\mathbb N, n\geq n_{k+1}\implies |y_{n_{k+1}}-\ell|<\frac{1}{2(k+1)}.$$

By definition of $y_{n_k}$,
$$\exists m_k\geq k :|y_{n_{k}}-x_{n_{m_k}}|<\frac{1}{2k}.$$

Let show that $(n_{m_k})_{k\in\mathbb N^*}$ is strictly increasing. Since $(n_p)_{p\in\mathbb N^*}$ est strictly increasing, we just have to show that $(m_k)_{k\in\mathbb N^*}$ is strictly increasing too to conclude that $(n_{m_k})_{k\in\mathbb N^*}$ is strictly increasing. Suppose by contradiction that it's not strictly increasing, i.e. that
$$\left[y_{n_{k+1}}-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}, y_{n_{k+1}}\right)\cap\{x_{n_p}\mid p>m_k\}=\emptyset.$$ 
If $m_k=k$, we have a contradiction with the existence of $y_{n_{k+1}}$, then we can suppose that $m_{k}\geq k+1$. Therefore,
$$y_{n_{k+1}}=\max_{p=k+1,...,m_k}x_{n_p},$$
and thus, for all $q\geq 1$, 
$$y_{n_{k+q}}=\max_{p=k+q,...,m_k}x_{n_p}.$$
However, for all $q>k-m_{k}$, we have that $y_{n_q}$ doesn't exist, which is a contradiction with the fact that $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$ converge. Then, the sequence $(m_k)_{k\in\mathbb N^*}$ can be supposed strictly increasing.

To conclude,

$$|x_{n_{m_k}}-\ell|\leq |x_{n_{m_k}}-y_{n_{k}}|+|y_{n_{k}}-\ell|\leq\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k}=\frac{1}{k}\underset{k\to\infty }{\longrightarrow }0,$$
and thus, $(x_{n_{m_k}})_{k\in\mathbb N^*}$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$ that converge.

Comment: Looks good.  But I don't know what $\mathbb{N}^*$ is.

Comment: the use of the iterated subscript in $x_{n_{m_k}}$ is a neat way to handle the extraction of the convergent subsequence, having used the inf sup operator to select a suitable target for convergence.

Comment: Actually it would reduce scary notation with triple subscripts if you just said "by definition of $y_{n_k}$, there is an $m_k \geq n_k$ such that $|y_{n_k}-x_{m_k}| \leq 1/(2k)$. But that is just a cosmetic issue.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I corrected it, thanks :-)

Comment: @idm Actually there is a problem with this proof.  You have to make sure the sequence of natural numbers $n_{m_k}$ is strictly increasing.  I don't think you guarantee that anywhere, do you?

Comment: @Gregory: You right, this was my problem actually. I'll think about that, thankd :-)

Comment: @idm I went ahead and posted my comment and response to your follow-up comment, as an answer

Comment: @Michael: Actually it's $m_k\geq k$. Indeed, $y_{n_k}=\sup_{j\geq k}x_{n_j}$

Comment: I thought $y_{n_k} = \sup_{j \geq n_k} x_{j}$ (just applying the definition).  If your other result is also true by some property of the $x_{n_j}$ sequence, it kind of puts a lot of burden on the reader to keep track of all these subscripts. If you want to make sure the indices diverge to infinity, why not just choose $n_k$ larger than $n_{k-1}$ and such that the desired property $|y_{n_k}-l|< 1/(2k)$ holds?

Comment: The fact that we can choose $n_k>n_{k-1}$ is a consequence of the convergence of $(y_n)$. I think that I have shown that $(n_{m_k})$ is strictly increasing. You can see the proof as a comment to the answer of Gregory Grant. If any body has time, tell me if you are satisfy. Thanks :-)

Comment: Can you tell if this proof is correct :-)

Comment: @idm I hope you don't mind I changed your interval notation to be more standard.  I'll try to find a minute later to check the logic.

Comment: @G.Grant: Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a problem with this proof.  You have to make sure the sequence of natural numbers $n_{m_k}$ is strictly increasing.  I don't think you guarantee that anywhere, do you?

That's why you have to define $n_{m_k}$ iteratively, since at each step there are infinitely many subscripts that satisfy the condition, you can always find one further out than the previous.

Otherwise it's a real nice proof, nice and concise.  I wonder, however, if you can't simplify it further, because you never actually use that $y_n$ converges.  If you do that maybe you can avoid the triple subscript.

Comment: I won't have time to check today, if I can I'll look tomorrow.

Comment: thanks a lot :-) Good evening :-)

Comment: I changed a little bit the proof (see on my question). Are satisfy ? Thanks :-)